# Forward Declaration necessary for nested friend classes

Tags: c++, class, nested, declaration, forward

Suppose I have two classes defined like so:

```
class obj1
{
  private:
    int mem;
    void method1();

  friend class obj2;
};

class obj2
{
  public:
    void method2();
};

void obj2::method2()
{
  obj1 test;
  test.mem = 59999;
  std::cout << test.mem;
  return;
}
```

This works great.  In main, if I declare an object of type obj2 and then call its method2 member function, it can successfully access private variables from an instance of obj1.  Now, suppose I make these classes nested:

```
class parent
{
  public:
  class obj1
  {
    private:
      int mem;
      void method1();

    friend class obj2;
  };

  class obj2
  {
    public:
      void method2();
  };
  void my_function();
};

void parent::obj2::method2()
{
  obj1 test;
  test.mem = 59999;
  std::cout << test.mem;
  return;
}

void parent::my_function()
{
  obj2 test2;
  obj2.method2();
  return;
}
```

This will not compile.  It says that "mem" is private, even though obj2 was declared as a friend class.  The only way I can fix this is by putting the forward declaration of class obj2 before the definition for the Class of obj1.  Yet I don't have to do that if the classes aren't nested.  **Why is this?**

Comment: It is a good practice to keep declarations and friend declarations separated and have a forward header to all types (and methods) that must be included before declaring a friend. This way you can avoid all kind of nasty problems. Notice that you "working" first case can get rather troublesome as you actually declare `obj2` class inside of obj1.

Comment: Probably difficult implementing a compiler to look ahead for declarations of nested classes, so they didn't bother. That's my guess for "why".

Comment: Wow, thank you, that's actually really insightful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A class declared to be `friend` is looked up in the context of the `friend` declaration. If one is found, this class is made a `friend`. If none is found the class is declared at the closest namespace level and this class is made a `friend`. The `friend` declaration will not introduce a nested class name. It would make a found nested class a `friend`, though.